# Parse HTML document with Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm pretty new parsing HTML documents and I'm stuck in this problem.

Giving an HTML document made like this:

```
<h3>File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMMainThread.h</h3>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<h4>Function: ::OMMainThread::destroyThread()</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">1</td></tr>
</table>
<h3>File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMNullValue.h</h3>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<h4>Function: ::OMNullValue<p{c::Ping}>::get()</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">2</td></tr>
</table>
<h4>Function: ::OMNullValue<p{c::Ping}>::initNullBlock()</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">5</td></tr>
</table>
<h4>Function: ::OMNullValue<p{c::Pong}>::get()</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">2</td></tr>
</table>
<h4>Function: ::OMNullValue<p{c::Pong}>::initNullBlock()</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">5</td></tr>
</table>
<h3>File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMStaticArray.h</h3>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<h4>Function: ::OMStaticArray<p{c::Ping}>::@constructor(,ni)</h4>
<table class="metricstable" width="100%">
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Metric</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">CALLS (STCAL)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">v(G) (STCYC)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">GOTO (STGTO)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">RETURN (STM19)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">LEVEL (STMIF)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PARAM (STPAR)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">PATH (STPTH)</td><td class="lightheader" align="right">STMT (STST3)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="lightheader" align="left">Values</td><td align="right">4</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">1</td><td align="right">2</td><td align="right">2</td></tr>
</table>
```

what I need is to create a data structure made like this:

<Filename, function (related to that file), STCYC value of that function>

I tried iterating like this:

```
for files_and_functions in soup.find_all(['h3','h4','table']):
        for elem in files_and_functions:
            valore = elem.text
```

and asking for each elem if it's a function, a file or a STCYC value, but I can't get out of it.
Is there anyone who can obtain these information from this terrible HTML? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `html_doc` contains the HTML snippet from your question you can do:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for t in soup.select("table.metricstable:not(:has(table))"):
    k = [td.text for td in t.tr.find_all("td")]
    v = [td.text for td in t.tr.find_next("tr").find_all("td")]

    d = dict(zip(k, v))

    filename = t.find_previous("h3").text
    function = t.find_previous("h4").text
    styc = d["v(G) (STCYC)"]

    print("{:<50} {:<10} {}".format(function, styc, filename))
```

Prints:

```
Function: ::OMMainThread::destroyThread()          1          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMMainThread.h
Function: ::OMNullValue::get()                     1          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMNullValue.h
Function: ::OMNullValue::initNullBlock()           2          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMNullValue.h
Function: ::OMNullValue::get()                     1          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMNullValue.h
Function: ::OMNullValue::initNullBlock()           2          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMNullValue.h
Function: ::OMStaticArray::@constructor(,ni)       2          File: /home/finxadm/XMW.SET.OXF.CPP/LangCpp/oxf/OMStaticArray.h
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot. However, even though I copied and pasted your code snippet, I got this error:
styc = d["v(G) (STCYC)"]
KeyError: 'v(G) (STCYC)'

I really don't know why, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ValeTrut Try `styc = d.get("v(G) (STCYC)", 'Not Found')`

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this

```
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = #the HTML code you've written above
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs={'class':'container'}).text)
```